# Octave: Change (only) height of plot window

Tags: image, plot, octave, eps

I made a plot using

```
h = figure;
x = 1:0.1:13;
plot(x, x, [';straight line;']);
print(h, 'graph.eps', '-color', '-deps', '-F:16');
```

which gives me

[image: x vs. x square plot]

I want to increase just the height of the plotting window. I added the pbaspect([1 2]); line:

```
h = figure;
x = 1:0.1:13;
plot(x, x, [';straight line;']);
pbaspect([1 2]);
print(h, 'graph.eps', '-color', '-deps', '-F:16');
```

but I get a messed up plot:

[image: messed up plot after changing aspect ratio]

I then changed the F:16 to F:8

```
h = figure;
x = 1:0.1:13;
plot(x, x, [';straight line;']);
pbaspect([1 2]);
print(h, 'graph.eps', '-color', '-deps', '-F:8');
```

and it works, but the resulting file still has the white margins on the sides(which you can see if you see the image below separately):

[image: smaller plot with proper ratios]

I want the final eps file to have the plot without the white margins. How can I achieve this?

The images were converted from eps to jpg using "convert graph.eps graph.jpg". However, they are meant to be used in a LaTeX document as eps images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, try adding the `-tight` option to `print`:

```
`-loose'
`-tight'
      Force a tight or loose bounding box for eps files.  The
      default is loose.
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that 'epstool' needs to be installed for this.